# Flexbox not working correctly on iPad 3 with Safari

Tags: html, ios, css, safari, flexbox

I've a problem with my `flexbox`. When I'm in Chrome or any other browser, everything works fine.

But when I'm on an iPad 3 with Safari, my `flexbox` is not working correctly. I've used `-webkit-` but it's still not working.

The `img` must be absolute positioned because otherwise the a link get's the hight of the `img` which otherwise destroys my whole navigation.

As you can see in the picture, the icon is not longer centered so `align-items` don't works:

[image]

And this is how it must look like:

[image]

So how can I fix this?

```css
li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 5em;
}

a {
    padding-right: 46px !important;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

a img {
    width: 35px;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<li>
<a href="https://www.google.de" aria-current="page">Max Mustermann
  <img alt="" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/200px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png" class="avatar avatar-70 photo wpfla round-avatars " width="70" height="70">
</a>
</li>
```

Comment: use `display: -webkit-flex;` instead `display: -webkit-box;`

Comment: Not working mate.

Comment: Please help me :(

Comment: use `inline` instead `flex`

Comment: And now my image is always not centered

Comment: here is example:https://jsfiddle.net/bpknyg36/

Comment: @לבנימלכה But now you've centered it with setting a -9px to the img what I wanted to prevent.

Comment: see now:https://jsfiddle.net/ko92nzem/

Answer (score 0):

Use below css for `align-items`

```
align-items: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;
```

```css
li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 5em;
}

a {
    padding-right: 46px !important;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

a img {
    width: 35px;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<li>
<a href="https://www.google.de" aria-current="page">Max Mustermann
  <img alt="" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/200px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png" class="avatar avatar-70 photo wpfla round-avatars " width="70" height="70">
</a>
</li>
```

Comment: This is what I did ;) It takes the normal display: flex and the normal align-items. Your code is lined thru.